# How to pull Facebook events from certain user

Tags: php, facebook, httprequest, pull

I am trying to create a script that will pull a Facebook user's event information (time, place, name) and place it onto a calendar for them to view. I can't seem to find a way to access the user's event data. I have a login page, where they grant the website the ability to access their event data. Here is the Event API section of the Facebook Developer Site: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/. So my main question is: What would a script that pulls all of the user's current events look like?

Comment: Would this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428838/facebook-restful-php-client-get-events-of-a-user

Comment: no, that post regards creating events, where I want to pull data from events that have already been created. Thanks though

Comment: I was looking specifically at events.get - the only reference to creating events I saw looks like the last comment in the accepted answer. I'm able to use their test harness here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.get/) to get the event details for a concert being held by a friend tomorrow. The event ID (eid) for that is 125846280835477 if you'd like to use it for testing.

Comment: i think that's just what i need. thank you

Comment: NP - if you're in the Nashville area, he'd love for you to come to the concert, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

A few months ago I made a PHP/HTML calendar that pulls a user or page's facebook events and puts them into the calendar on your website.

I hope this helps:

https://github.com/dangreenisrael/facebook-calendar/